# Constructing a Pattern object using a pre-determined Pattern object

Tags: java, regex, constructor

am using the Pattern class for the first time as part of a Uni assignment in which we have to create a parser and interpreter. This is how I'm currently defining the Pattern's I'm using:

```
    private static Pattern OPENBRACE = Pattern.compile("\\{");
private static Pattern CLOSEBRACE = Pattern.compile("\\}");

private static Pattern blockPat = Pattern.compile("OPENBRACE [stmtPat]+ CLOSEBRACE");
private static Pattern loopPat = Pattern.compile("loop blockPat");
private static Pattern actPat = Pattern.compile("move | turnL | turnR | takeFuel |      wait");
private static Pattern stmtPat = Pattern.compile("actPat; | loopPat");
private static Pattern progPat = Pattern.compile("[stmtPat]*");
```

As you can see I'm trying to create new Pattern objects defined by a pre-determined Pattern object.

Currently Java is treating the input ".compile("....")" as a string literal and not recognising the variable names. Is there any way I can define a Pattern the way I want too? Or do I have to define each Pattern based LITERALLY on the lexicographic strings each Pattern should be searching for?

Answer (score 0):

Compiling regex is more than just identifying key characters, it involves putting together a plan for how the whole regex needs to operate. Lookaheads, captures, etc. It's not just about making a string.
You'd be best served by just having a String for OPENBRACE, and concatenating that into your other patterns.

As you can see from the Java 6 source, compiling a pattern has a good amount of work put into it. It doesn't accept nested Patterns.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/regex/Pattern.java#Pattern.compile%28%29

EDIT: in addition, there's no possible way that a new Pattern could know to reference the OPENBRACE pattern, because you're using that name as a literal, not a reference. There's a huge difference between

```
"OPENBRACE" // a string
```

and

```
OPENBRACE // a variable reference
```

Comment: Thanks! In response to your "EDIT:.." point, yes I realise that. I've also tried concatenating using the variable OPENBRACE. "OPENBRACE" was simply used as an example. So, to answer my question, there's no way to create a Pattern object using a predetermined Pattern?